# What is the difference between Apache + OpenSSL and Apache + mod SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I am moving from self-signed certificates to a signed certificate.  I am using namecheap and positive SSL.

There are options for Apache + OpenSSL and Apache + mod SSL.

It was my impression that mod SSL just used the OpenSSL functionality.

I plan to generate the keys/certs using something similar to:

```
touch smtpd.key
chmod 600 smtpd.key
openssl genrsa 2048 > smtpd.key
openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -x509 -days 365 -out smtpd.crt # has prompts
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365
```

and placing them in the appropriate places.

Which option should I choose to complete the process?  I am using openssl to create the certificate, but mod ssl is enabled in the apache server.  Or am I correct in assuming these two options do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_ssl` is an apache module that makes the openssl functions available to apache. So these options are really the same.

Briefly looking at namecheap's website, I don't see either of the options you mentioned, but go for 'apache with mod_ssl'.